# How to get at target element with jQuery event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have an event listener, and an element that triggers a custom event on click. They’re set up as follows:

```
$(document).on('customEventName', function(e) {
    // do something
});

$(document).on('click', '[data-action]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).trigger( $(this).attr('action') );
});
```

Say I have an anchor tag (`<a href="#" data-target="customEventName">`) trigger the `click` event, how would I then get at that `<a>` tag and its properties in my listener? I’m wanting to get at the object to parse any additional `data-` attributes.

Comment: Little confused, seems you're already using `this`, you want to pass the instance of `this` onto your custom listener?

Answer (score 5):

## Solution 1: `extraParameters`

Use `extraParamters` parameter as second argument of `trigger` jQuery function.

```
$(document).on('customEventName', function(e, dataActionElement) {
    // do something
});

$(document).on('click', '[data-action]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).trigger($(this).attr('action'), [$(this)]);
});
```

From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

### `.trigger( event [, extraParameters ] )`

- event

  > Type: Event
  >
  > A jQuery.Event object.
- extraParameters

  > Type: Array or PlainObject
  >
  > Additional parameters to pass along to the event handler.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2WLhf/2/)

---

## Solution 2: custom events

According to [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), you also can create a custom `Event` where you can set the target:

### Category: `Event` Object

> jQuery’s event system normalizes the event object according to W3C standards. The event object is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler. Most properties from the original event are copied over and normalized to the new event object.

```
$(document).on('customEventName', function(e) {
    // e.target is clicked element sent using customEvent
    // do something
});

$(document).on('click', '[data-action]', function(e) {
    var customEvent = $.Event($(this).attr('action'), {target: this }) 
    $(document).trigger(customEvent);
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BuvsZ/3/)

Comment: This is kinda what I’m after, but I thought I’d be able to access the caller in `.on('customEventName')` in the `e` parameter, without having to pass the caller object as an extra parameter?

Comment: @MartinBean Why would you do that? I don't see any reason, because this solution is also simple.

Comment: It just seems to be the obvious way to use an event listener. Something triggers an event, you then interrogate the caller in your listener?

Comment: @MartinBean Updated my answer. Added the content.

Comment: @MartinBean Is it ok now?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it as a parameter in trigger:

```
$(document).on('customEventName', function(e, target) {
    // do something
});

$(document).on('click', '[data-action]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).trigger( $(this).attr('action'), [this] );
});
```

you could also try something like this:

```
$(document).on('customEventName', function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    // do something
});

$(document).on('click', '[data-action]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var customEvent = $.Event($(this).data('action'), { target: this });
    $(document).trigger( customEvent );
});
```